# Java Showing Error NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, exception, nosuchfileexception

I am trying to develop a java application for cruise control system. But I am having a problem in no such file exception. As I am little bit new in java coding. I am not sure why this problem is occurring. My Code is-

```
 public static void main(String[] commandLineArgs) throws IOException {
    Path input_path = Paths.get(commandLineArgs[0]);
    List<InputState> input_states = StateInput.input_states_from_file(input_path);
    Timer timer = new Timer(new CruiseControlSystem());
    List<OutputState> output_states = timer.pulse_from_input(input_states);
    for (OutputState s : output_states){
        System.out.println(s.format());
    }
}
```

And the Error I found is -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: commandLineArgs[0]
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Unknown Source)
at StateInput.input_states_from_file(StateInput.java:31)
at CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:23)
```

My Main Method is -

```
public static void main(String[] commandLineArgs) throws IOException {
    Path input_path = Paths.get(commandLineArgs[0]);
    List<InputState> input_states = StateInput.input_states_from_file(input_path);
    Timer timer = new Timer(new CruiseControlSystem());
    List<OutputState> output_states = timer.pulse_from_input(input_states);
    for (OutputState s : output_states){
        System.out.println(s.format());
     }
 }
```

[image: image of run configuration]

Answer (score 0):

In the *Program Arguments* textbox you currently have "**commandLineArgs[0]**". You need to change "**commandLineArgs[0]**" to the path to your file containing the input states. Something like "**/data/input-states**".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> My main method is:

```
Path input_path = Paths.get(commandLineArgs[0]);
```

No it isn't. You are passing `"commandLineArgs[0]"` as the argument. You mean `commandLineArgs[0]`, without the quotation marks.

Answer (score -1):

You are not passing any arguments to main method while running the program.

Can you also add how are you running this.

Comment: @kushagra_mittal I hav modified my question and gave main method

Comment: I am trying to run this with eclipse

Comment: You have to pass a single argument from eclipse. Go to Run Configurations. Look for tab  Arguments  and pass a single argument in Program Arguments. This will resolve your issue. If you want i can post a ScreenShot for same

Comment: I am a bit in java. Can you please explain me how can I do that

Comment: Right Click on you java class, there will be a tab Run As when you expand that you will see run configuration. Open that and set the argument. Let me post a ScreenShot so that you will be more clear.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/images/runConfigurationToolbarList.png
https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.5.0.RELEASE/docs/virgo-user-guide/htmlsingle/images/director_args.png
    
See these SS for help

Comment: Instead commandLineArgs[0] pass a path like "/home/ubuntu/file.txt" - Your input Path.

Comment: Yes, path to that file.

Comment: I am trying to chaange the argument but still it is not working

Comment: Is file is present at that location?  Are you still getting same exception?